Publish in Google Play (Unity + Vuforia)
i used https://github.com/google/play-unity-plugins/releases
for build(Googe Play) to aab file in unity
enter image description here
but build stoped this image forever

i builded in unity
i got aab file that vuforia aab exceeds 150mb

i used https://github.com/google/play-unity-plugins/releases
it stopped it in enter image description here

error


Exception failed: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.WaitHandle.Wait_internal(intptr*,int,bool,int)
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative (System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, System.UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Boolean hasThreadAffinity, System.Boolean exitContext) [0x00044] in :0
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne (System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, System.Int64 millisecondsTimeout, System.Boolean hasThreadAffinity, System.Boolean exitContext) [0x00014] in :0
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (System.Int64 timeout, System.Boolean exitContext) [0x00000] in :0
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Boolean exitContext) [0x00019] in :0
at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit (System.Int32 milliseconds) [0x00024] in :0
at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit () [0x00000] in :0
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit()
at Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.PlayServices.CommandLine.RunViaShellInternal (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue] envVars, Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.PlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler, System.Boolean useShellExecution, System.Boolean stdoutRedirectionInShellMode) [0x00341] in C:\Users\JKKim\Desktop\240604_Vuforia\Assets\GooglePlayPlugins\com.google.android.appbundle\Editor\Scripts\Internal\PlayServices\CommandLine.cs:645  at Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.PlayServices.CommandLine.RunViaShell (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue] envVars, Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.PlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler, System.Boolean useShellExecution, System.Boolean stdoutRedirectionInShellMode) [0x00022] in C:\Users\JKKim\Desktop\240604_Vuforia\Assets\GooglePlayPlugins\com.google.android.appbundle\Editor\Scripts\Internal\PlayServices\CommandLine.cs:541
at Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.PlayServices.CommandLine.Run (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue] envVars, Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.PlayServices.CommandLine+IOHandler ioHandler) [0x00000] in C:\Users\JKKim\Desktop\240604_Vuforia\Assets\GooglePlayPlugins\com.google.android.appbundle\Editor\Scripts\Internal\PlayServices\CommandLine.cs:504  at Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.ZipUtils.UnzipFile (System.String zipFilePath, System.String outputDirectoryName) [0x00011] in C:\Users\JKKim\Desktop\240604_Vuforia\Assets\GooglePlayPlugins\com.google.android.appbundle\Editor\Scripts\Internal\BuildTools\ZipUtils.cs:80  at Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder.CreateBaseModule (System.IO.DirectoryInfo baseWorkingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.IList1[System.String]& bundleMetadata) [0x0001c] in C:\Users\JKKim\Desktop\240604_Vuforia\Assets\GooglePlayPlugins\com.google.android.appbundle\Editor\Scripts\Internal\BuildTools\AppBundleBuilder.cs:809
at Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder.CreateBaseModules (System.Collections.Generic.IList1[T] moduleDirectoryList, Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.CreateBundleOptions options, System.IO.DirectoryInfo workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.IList1[System.String]& bundleMetadata) [0x00014] in C:\Users\JKKim\Desktop\240604_Vuforia\Assets\GooglePlayPlugins\com.google.android.appbundle\Editor\Scripts\Internal\BuildTools\AppBundleBuilder.cs:426
at Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder.CreateBundle (Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.CreateBundleOptions options) [0x00051] in C:\Users\JKKim\Desktop\240604_Vuforia\Assets\GooglePlayPlugins\com.google.android.appbundle\Editor\Scripts\Internal\BuildTools\AppBundleBuilder.cs:203
at Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass43_0.b__0 () [0x00000] in C:\Users\JKKim\Desktop\240604_Vuforia\Assets\GooglePlayPlugins\com.google.android.appbundle\Editor\Scripts\Internal\BuildTools\AppBundleBuilder.cs:238
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder:DisplayBuildError (string,string) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AppBundleBuilder.cs:988)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder/<>c__DisplayClass43_0:b__0 () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AppBundleBuilder.cs:245)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart ()

Hi @semi, have you tried following this page in the Vuforia documentation? https://developer.vuforia.com/library/unity-extension/building-large-vuforia-engine-apps-unity
